# validate url with regular expressions

Tags: php, regex

I've gone through all possible ways for having the regular expression for the url validation,
but I didn't get any..
what I need is the url can be like

```
google.com
http://google.com
https://google.com
http://www.google.com
https://www.google.com
```

but it should not allow if it is just `google`

finally the thing is the `.extensions` are mandatory

I've tried this `/^[a-z0-9-]+(.[a-z0-9-]*)(.[a-z0-9-]*)$/`

can anyone help me in this case..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this Expression

```
/[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,4}\b(\/[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)?/gi
```

It will aceept all the cases that you have mentioned above

Comment: I'm not familiar with regular expression. Would you please give me the php code?

Comment: Been using this regex for a while and ran into a .financial site.... so the {2,4} for the top level domain should be {2,9}

Answer (score 8):

You can directly validate url using `filter_var` and `FILTER_VALIDATE_URL`

```
if (filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) !== false)
```

**Edit**

With **Regex**

```
$subject = "http://www.google.com";
$pattern = "/\b(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/|www\.)[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|]/i";
preg_match($pattern, $subject, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

## Output

```
Array ( [0] => http://www.google.com )
```

## Codepad

Comment: I'm validating with the regular expression which will be stored in my database, I cannot use these kind of conditions..

Comment: Why not, use it before inserting in database.

Comment: @Nagendra see edited answer for regular expression.

Comment: Nice one, but it won't validate some protocols, for example if you want to validate stream URLs you should change this part  
`(?:https?|ftp)`  
to this  
`(?:https?|ftp|rtmp|rtsp|mms)`  
is possible I'm missing others

Answer (score 1):

```
((https?:|[^.])\/\/w{0,3}[.]?google.[a-z]{2,4})|google.[a-z]{2,4}
```

It is not the prettiest but it works. I've checked with http://regexpal.com/

Comment: Let me propose several improvements. **1** you could use `https?` this will match both http or https, **2** you don't need to put the `w` in a character class, **3** `{0,1}` means `?` so you can make it `\.?`. Although this regex just works for this example, what if I had `http://translate.google.com` or `http://google.fr` ?

Comment: Yes you're right about some improvements. He wanted it for examples he gave so I wrote it for that examples. If he wants domain It can be easily added. I've answered what he wanted or what I thought he wanted :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following

```
(^(http|https)://)?(www\.)?\w+\.com
```

Comment: it doesn't match "google.com"

Comment: Still not working http://regexpal.com/ check it.

Comment: Working for me.Also tested on http://www.regextester.com/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create really good domain validator you should get database of domain tlds and make validation for them.

Mozilla has that list: http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/netwerk/dns/effective_tld_names.dat?raw=1

Here is a python module for that https://github.com/nmmmnu/TLDExtractor