# Check if the URL is valid

Tags: php

I'm creating a little script where i wanna check whether a specific url is valid. I've found a this function below to do this. However this only returns true if it starts with `http://` is it possible to make so that it also accept a url like following

```
www.example.com
example.com
```

Code:

```
if (filter_var('http://www.example.com', FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) !== FALSE) {
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2280394/how-can-i-check-if-a-url-exists-via-php

Comment: use regex to validate, check answer.

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16436491/1635676

Comment: possible duplicate of [validate url with regular expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16434017/validate-url-with-regular-expressions)

Comment: `filter_var` is a good choice unlike creating crippled self-made regex validators. If you want it to tolerate the missing schema, then just check if the string starts with http(s?)://, and add it yourself if it doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following regex approach...

```
function is_url_valid($url)
{
    if(! preg_match('/^(https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]*)*\/?$/', $url))
    {
        return false;    
    }
    else return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way is to, if the check fails, just slap `http://` in front of it and try that, too. If that works, chances are quite good it's a valid http url that just left the `http://` part out. The function `filter_var()` is definitely the proper way to do it. Writing your own regexes, trying to download an address, etc., is completely unnecessary.